# Function of list

Tags: functions, function-construction

Suppose we define a generic function `f[x_]:=x^2` and pass an argument to it: `x={1,2,3}; f[x]`. Does this operation imply that a physical copy of list `x` is created somewhere in the memory and this new physical copy is substituted in the first occurence line in the body of the function, and from that point on the function's body starts being evaluated line by line?

I have a feeling this question was asked before under some other title that didn't manage to locate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematica uses [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write). No copies are made until necessary. Passing an argument to a function does not cause a copy to be made.

Comment: Thanks, @Szabolcs. Can you clarify what exactly 'until necessary' means for mathematica? Until any modification or something more than that?

Comment: @AlGuy Yes, until any modification.